# How to replace this with a single click download in table itself

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Curently I have to right click to download. I want a simple button in table to download.

```
<div id="menu-file-clone" style="display: none;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="custom-menu-list file-option download"><span><i class="fa fa-download"></i> </span>Download</a>
</div>



$('.file-item').bind("contextmenu", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.file-item').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    var custom =$("<div class='custom-menu file'></div>")
        custom.append($('#menu-file-clone').html())
        custom.find('.download').attr('data-id',$(this).attr('data-id'))
    custom.appendTo("body")
    custom.css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});

    
    $("div.file.custom-menu .download").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        window.open('download.php?id='+$(this).attr('data-id'))
    })

    

})
```

I tried but its not working when I am shifting the div inside the td block.

Comment: So remove all that JS code, and make the href attribute of that link point to `download.php?id=...` directly?